# Is it pages_show_list enough for getting instagram_business_accounts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

That Facebook Graph API docs are not the best in the world I guess it's something more than well known.

The fact is that we are creating an app to access to Instagram Business Accounts data. Facebook documentation, in the [Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) guide, says to use `manage_pages` permission to get the list of instagram business accounts linked to pages. The problem of that permission is that requires application review and that, under our previous experience, takes between 4 and 6 weeks to happen. Also, we don't want to manage user pages, just get the Instagram Business Accounts linked to them.

So we have tried to use `pages_show_list` instead. But in the tests I have made, I only can see the Instagram Business Account linked to a page I manage, while using `manage_pages`(same query on Graph API Explorer) I get the two Instagram Business Accounts I have linked to Facebook pages. I have the same `tasks` (roles) for both pages.

That makes me wonder if it's that `pages_show_list` for whatever reason doesn't work for that, or it's something specific about the second page/Instagram Business Account that I do not achieve to understand.

Comment: Either one of those permissions requires review, so deciding which to use based on _that_ criterion makes rather little sense to begin with.

Comment: Sorry @misorude, maybe I explain myself badly. `pages_show_list` [does not require review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-pages_show_list).

Comment: Oh, you’re right, the must have changed that, used to be that all permissions besides the three basic ones required review. Not sure if that’s supposed to work with `pages_show_list` only. Not sure what your exact situation is either though, what’s the difference between “the Instagram Business Account linked to a page I manage” and “two Instagram Business Accounts I have linked to Facebook pages” exactly?

Comment: @misorude that's the point, in theory there is no difference. I have two differente Instagram Business Accounts (A and B), both are linked to a Facebook Page (A' and B'), I have permissions to manage both pages, but when I ask to the accounts endpoint (`/me/accounts/`) I can see both pages but only can see the Instagram Business Account for one of them. `/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account` does not show any Instagram Business Account for, lets say, Facebook Page B' if my token has granted `pages_show_list`, but shows IG Business Accounts for A' and B' if has granted `manage_pages`

Comment: Did you add those IG accounts to the Facebook pages yourself, or did maybe a different page admin do that for B? Could be that Facebook differentiates based on that.

Comment: @misorude, no, I added both. But seems l found the key [in documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page#read) (_Permissions_ sub-section). Even when I have no clear to have made it one via **Business Manager** and the another one in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests looks like `manage_pages` is a must to get Instagram Business Accounts connected to Facebook Pages.

After three different users testing, each of them owning two different Facebook Pages connected to two different Instagram Business Accounts, I was the only one who achieved to see one of the Instagram accounts with a token with `pages_show_list` granted permission.

Why I can see that account? I don't know, but definitely that's the weird case and it's not possible, in general, get the Instagram Business Account connected to a Facebook Page with a user token with `pages_show_list` as permission instead of `manage_pages`.

**UPDATE:** I've finally find [a hint on the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page#read). Looks like the difference is made if the role permissions to the Page are granted to the user via **Business Manager** or not. If they have been granted in that way, apart from `pages_show_list`, in theory one of `manages_pages`, `business_management` or `ads_management` permissions are needed.

Even when I don't know how to know if the Page permissions/role has been given in that way, I've tried it and it worked for me with `pages_show_list` + `manage_pages` and `pages_show_list` + `business_management` but not with `pages_show_list` + `ads_management`.